# How to loop through an array of objects that have been decoded from JSON in PHP, and echo the values

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm new to PHP and am not sure how to proceed. The array that I get back from decoding the JSOn is: (sorry if its formatted weird)

```
array(3) {
 [0]=> array(4) { 
   ["Name"]=> string(22) "Brent's Medical Center"
   ["date"]=> string(26) "/Date(1330449077600-0700)/"
   ["dealType"]=> string(13) "Capital Lease" 
   ["id"]=> string(11) "MO-N007175A" 
 } 
 [1]=> array(4) { 
   ["Name"]=> string(22) "Brent's Medical Center" 
   ["date"]=> string(26) "/Date(1330448929213-0700)/" 
   ["dealType"]=> string(2) "NA"  ..... ["id"]=> string(11) "MO-N007172Q" } [2]=> array(4) { ["Name"]=> string(15) "MOC" ["date"]=> string(28) "/Date(-62135571600000-0700)/" ["dealType"]=> string(2) "NA" ["id"]=> string(9) "MC" } }
```

I have used this foreach loop, but am not sure how to get each individual item out of an associative array.

```
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    print_r($key);
}
```

This returns:

```
012
```

I have tried other solutions, but to no avail. Maybe I'm not understanding completely what's happening, but I can't get anything to do what I need/want.
Thanks!

Comment: To clarify what I'm doing - I need to print out the data in a table format. So each array will essentially be it's own row, and each individual piece will be its own cell. That's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nested objects, try the following:

```
echo '<table>';

foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $value->Name . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $value->date . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $value->dealType . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $value->id . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: when I echo the $value["Name"] or whatever else, it echo's nothing and the rest of my script stops.

Comment: Can you add <?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); ?> to the top of your script and see if that reports a descriptive error?

Comment: It doesn't output anything. =(

Comment: Can you put the result of <?php print_r($obj); ?> in your question?

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /www/medo****/***.php on line 85

Comment: Except obviously the stars arent there... I added those.

Comment: What if you change $value["Name"] to $value->Name what happens?

Comment: Objects and arrays must be accessed using different syntax unless an object implements ArrayAccess.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends exactly how you want it returned.

```
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
   print_r($value);
}
```

Would return your data like this:

```
array(4) { 
 ["Name"]=> string(22) "Brent's Medical Center"
 ["date"]=> string(26) "/Date(1330449077600-0700)/"
 ["dealType"]=> string(13) "Capital Lease" 
 ["id"]=> string(11) "MO-N007175A" 
} 
array(4) { 
 ["Name"]=> string(22) "Brent's Medical Center" 
 ["date"]=> string(26) "/Date(1330448929213-0700)/" 
 ["dealType"]=> string(2) "NA"  
 ["id"]=> string(11) "MO-N007172Q" 
} 

... etc
```

If you wanted individual data pieces via your example, it would be like this:

```
foreach ($obj as $each_array) {
   foreach ($each_array as $val){
      echo $val . "<br>";
   }
}
```

Which would return:

```
Brent's MedicalCenter
/Date(1330449077600-0700)/
Capital Lease
... etc
```

Comment: This is really close - To clarify what I'm doing - I need to print out the data in a table format. So each array will essentially be it's own row, and each individual piece will be its own cell. That's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $data is what was var_dump'd in your pasted content:

```
foreach($data as $record) {
    //$record['name'] is now something like "Brent's medical center"
}
```

Note though that you'll have to process the date field into something more usable than a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is an array filled with associative arrays. So when you're doing your loop and  operating on `$key`, that's not the data, but the index of your parent array.
So simply changing the part of the array you're dealing with will fulfill your original code sample.

```
foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    print_r($value);
}
```

Now each `$value` is the associative array with the keys Name, date, dealType, etc. So you can get your values directly, e.g. `$value['Name']` for the first loop would be "Brent's Medical Center"

Comment: Thats closer - now how can I get the information out of the value array? Sorry.. I'm a total newb.

Comment: Exactly as I mentioned after the code sample: `$value['Name']` (modified further to attempt to be more clear). Is there something else you're trying to do besides that?

Comment: When I try and echo the $value['Name'] it returns the entire $obj array, and the rest of my script stops.

Comment: Actually thats not whats happening - sorry. I still cant access individual pieces with echo $value['Name'];

Comment: To clarify what I'm doing - I need to print out the data in a table format. So each array will essentially be it's own row, and each individual piece will be its own cell. That's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hmm. Just out of pure curiosity, is 'Name' actually 'name'? Variables and keys in PHP are case-sensitive.

Comment: Nope - Name is indeed "Name". I clarified what I'm trying to do with the table in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Script echo's exactly what you ask it to echo - array keys(indexes). Array has 3 values, so its keys are 0, 1, 2.

Looks like you need `$value` variable insode foreach-loop.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified version of your problem. Substitute your array for the one here.

```
<?php
$arr[0] = array('uno'=>'one', 'dos'=>'two');
$arr[1] = array('AAAA'=>'aaaa', 'BBBB'=>'bbbb');

foreach ($arr as $obj) {
    foreach ($obj as $k=>$v) {
        echo "key:$k=>val:$v\n";
    }
}
?>
```

If you want to access something specific, you can do it like this:

```
echo $arr[1]["BBBB"]; // echoes bbbb
```

Or...

```
echo $arr[1]["Name"]; // echoes Brent's Medical Center
```